# Django "login() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" error

Tags: django

I'm trying to store the user's ID in the session using django.contrib.auth.login . But it is not working not as expected.

I'm getting error **login() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)**

With login(user) I'm getting **AttributeError at /login/ User' object has no attribute 'method'**

I'm using slightly modifyed example form [http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-to-log-a-user-in) :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
    msg = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['u']
        password = request.POST['p']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                msg.append("login successful")
            else:
                msg.append("disabled account")
        else:
            msg.append("invalid login")
    return render_to_response('login.html', {'errors': msg})
```

there's nothing special about login.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login/" method="post">
        Login:&nbsp; <input type="text" name="u">
    <br/>
        Password:&nbsp; <input type="password" name="p">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    {% if errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody have idea how to make login() work.

Comment: will work if you rename your view

Comment: Just the question and answer I was looking for. One of several mistakes I was making while trying to get logins up and running in django, along with using Contexts vs RequestContexts and leaving out csrf_tokens.

Comment: here you can find a tutorial about Django users http://lowcoupling.com/post/71289666862/django-the-user-tutorial there is also a GitHub project you can clone and check

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Your view function is also called `login`, and the call to `login(request, user)` ends up being interpreted as a attempt to call this function recursively:

```
def login(request):
    ...
    login(request, user)
```

To avoid it rename your view function or refer to the `login` from `django.contrib.auth` in some different way. You could for example change the import to rename the login function:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

...
auth_login(request, user)
```

Comment: Wow, I was browsing through Django's source code, and trying every older version available, thinking I was going insane

Answer (score 16):

One possible fix:

```
from django.contrib import auth

def login(request):
    # ....
    auth.login(request, user)
    # ...
```

Now your view name doesn't overwrite django's view name.

Answer (score 8):

Another way:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
```

then call `auth_login(request, user)` instead of `login(request, user)`.